# Display png template in Matplotlib graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am producing some 300+ graphs, 1 per page. When displaying these graphs I would like to include the border template my office uses for all our figures (ie single line border with information block in the bottom right corner). I have this template in a .png. I was hoping to just draw it onto each figure and then draw the graphs over the template:

draw template:

```
fig = plt.figure(Cnt_fig)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = plt.imread('TEST.png')
ax2.imdraw(im)
```

Then plot graphs:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
```

The issue I am having is that some of my graphs have a "non-linear axes" and the I get the error: `warnings.warn("Images are not supported on non-linear axes.")`

Any ideas?

Comment: How about if you use `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')`, does that solve anything?

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet?